# what video technology does mixergy.com use for its interviews?

Tags: macos, mac, video, chat

I know it is Mac-based but I have not been able to find it in my Mac. An example of a video chat taken with "the technology" is available in this link:

http://mixergy.com/amy-jo-kim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Warner at mixergy.com [once answered](http://mixergy.com/warren-jolly-affiliate-media/#comment-15716994) someone who asked this question. He said:

> The picture-in-picture layout is from Skype. The new format is from Ecamm,
>   a new recorder.

I suppose the recorder is [Call Recorder](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/) from Ecamm.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

Call Recorder - to record

ScreenFlow - to edit